# Relaxed graph coloring, with penalties for assigning adjacent vertices the same color

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard, colorings

Consider a set of $N$ nodes. There is a $N\times N$ non-negative valued matrix $D$ where the $(i,j)$th element $d_{ij}$ gives the "positive metric" between node $i$ and $j$, where $i,j\in [N]$. Thus the diagonal entries of $D$ are all zero and $d_{ij}=d_{ji}$ so $D$ is symmetric.

Then there is a set of  $k$ colors. I want to assign these colors to the $N$ nodes such that the minimum  metric of a common color between any pair of nodes is maximized. So if $c(i)$ is the color assigned to $i\in [N]$ by the assignment $a\in A$, where $A$ is the set of all possible color assignments, we are looking for $$\max_{a\in A} \min_{i,j} \{d_{ij}:c(i)=c(j)\}.$$

Is this problem NP-hard?  If it is, what sort of reduction can be used to show that this problem is NP-hard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Reduce from [graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity).

$D$ is given by $d_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } i=j \\ 1 & \text{ if } i \text{ is adjacent to } j \\ 2 & \text{ else}\end{cases}$.

Comment: So the graph coloring problem is solved iff the problem in the question has optimal value 2? Is that the argument? Thanks

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}\;$

Comment: I will use this in my research so that I can propose heuristic algorithms. I would like to acknowledge you. If you don't mind please let me know your credentials. Else I can acknowledge the forum. Also do you think my problem has been considered before? If so what sort of key words show I used to find that please?

Comment: It would be better to acknowledge the forum in this case, and your problem $\hspace{1.68 in}$ seems highly related to [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). $\;$

Comment: I think it is also necessary to acknowledge you personally for this contribution in my work. Would you mind that? I can put you as a author or in the acknowledgement section.

Comment: I wouldn't mind. $\:$ (Also, I just put my real name on my user page.) $\;\;\;$

Comment: Thanks. My paper proposes a game theory solution to a problem similar to this so I had to make sure it is NP-hard. I will email you my paper (if you may provide the email) when ready. What do I put for your affiliation and designation (title)?

Comment: UCSB, graduate student $\;$